# CSS div wrapper works with everything except these div tags. Why?

Tags: html, css

I have used a wrapper to center div tags and it works for everything except the css in the link

Please check out:

http://jsfiddle.net/T5rBU/3/

As you can see the pink box with text is in the center but the black box isn't.

I have put

```
float: left;
```

but that is only because if I don't the black box doesn't show!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
.center div {
     display:inline-block;   
     text-align:center;   
}
```

it seams to work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/u3ggV/

Comment: You're welcome. (If you think it is the right answer accept it so others can benefit from your question too)

Comment: Just a quick one, when I put my code into this site: http://jsfiddle.net/GJMtC/ the mouseovers work but when I write it in textedit and view it on my browser it doesnt? It worked like an hour ago but doesnt now?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that question in time, I'm always cleanings browser cache so I'm always losing my session. When you want to ask a new question do it in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask so everyone can see it and answer it, it's best for you and for the community. I don't have time right now so I hope you already figure out what was failing.

Answer (score 1):

add a with to .center

`.center {width:400px;}`

or another width you cant center div with `text-align`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow what you mean but I think it could be down to not having a wrapping element to hold both divs - http://jsfiddle.net/djsbaker/T5rBU/4/

Did you want the black box beside or above/below the navigation?